# Celery worker in docker won't get correct message broker

Tags: python, docker, flask, celery, docker-compose

I'm creating a flask service using an app factory pattern and I need to use celery for async tasks. I'm also using docker and docker-compose to contain and run everything. My structure looks like this:

```
server
 |
 +-- manage.py
 +-- docker-compose.yml
 +-- requirements.txt
 +-- Dockerfile
 |    
 +-- project
 |  |  
 |  +-- api
 |      |
 |      +--tasks.py
 |
 |  +-- __init__.py
```

My `tasks.py` file looks like this:

```
from project import celery_app

@celery_app.task
def celery_check(test):
    print(test)
```

I call `manage.py` to run which looks like this:

```
# manage.py

from flask_script import Manager
from project import create_app

app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

And my `__init__.py`looks like this:

```
# project/__init__.py

import os
import json
from flask_mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
from flask_cas import CAS
from flask import Flask
from itsdangerous import JSONWebSignatureSerializer as JWT
from flask_httpauth import HTTPTokenAuth
from celery import Celery

# instantiate the database and CAS
db = MongoAlchemy()
cas = CAS()

# Auth stuff (ReplaceMe is replaced below in create_app())
jwt = JWT("ReplaceMe")
auth = HTTPTokenAuth('Bearer')
celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL"))


def create_app():
    # instantiate the app
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='client/templates', static_folder='client/static')

    # set config
    app_settings = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
    app.config.from_object(app_settings)

    # Send new static files every time if debug is enabled
    if app.debug:
        app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0

    # Get the secret keys
    parse_secret(app.config['CONFIG_FILE'], app)

    celery_app.conf.update(app.config)
    print(celery_app.conf)

    # set up extensions
    db.init_app(app)
    cas.init_app(app)
    # Replace the secret key with the app's
    jwt.secret_key = app.config["SECRET_KEY"]

    parse_config(app.config['CONFIG_FILE'])

    # register blueprints
    from project.api.views import twist_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(twist_blueprint)

    return app
```

In my docker-compose I start a worker and define some environment variables like this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  twist-service:
    container_name: twist-service
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000 # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    environment:
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_NAME_TESTING=testing
      - DATABASE_NAME_DEV=dev
      - DATABASE_URL=twist-database
      - CONFIG_FILE=./project/default_config.json
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=user
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
    depends_on:
      - celery
      - twist-database
  celery:
    container_name: celery
    build: .
    command: celery -A project.api.tasks --loglevel=debug worker
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
  twist-database:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "twist-database"
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_USER=mongo
    volumes:
      - /data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017  # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    command: mongod
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - '/redis'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

However when I run my docker-compose file and generate the containers, I end up with this in the celery worker logs:

```
[2017-07-20 16:53:06,721: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

Which means the worker is ignoring the configuration set for redis when celery was created, and trying to use rabbitmq instead. I've tried changing the project.api.tasks to project and project.celery_app, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me like the `celery` service should have the environment variables `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` and `CELERY_BROKER_URL` as well.

Comment: I'm using those in my celery configuration in my flask app when I create the celery instance, this line is where it's used celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL"))

Comment: Yes but the celery service runs the command ```celery -A project.api.tasks --loglevel=debug worker```, and in this file (tasks), you retrieve the celery_app from ```projects```. There, you create the celery app (which must also exist worker-side!), but in this container, the broker url variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the docker services together.  The most straight-forward mechanism to do this is to add a [`networks` section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in your dockerfile.

Comment: I thought there was a default network created when you use docker compose? Plus the issue here is the worker is using rabbitmq when I have defined reddis as the message broker when I created the celery object